# Changing Declared SRS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am using PostGIS with geoserver. I have been able to publish a shapefile.zip as a layer.

The problem is, even though there is a .prj in the zip file, the Declared SRS in Geoserver is EPSG:404000

I would like to change it to EPSG:4326 using rest. The things I found, mention the xml to be used, but not how to implement it.

I get a 'Method is not allowed' error.

Here is the code I am using for doing it.

```
Dim gUrl As String = ("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/" & workspace & "/datastores/" & ds & "/featuretypes/alignment")

            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(gUrl)
            request.ContentType = "text/xml"
            request.Method = "PUT"
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "geoserver")
            Dim buffer() As Byte = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<featureType><srs>EPSG:4326</srs><projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy></featureType>")
            Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            requestStream.Close()
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
            Return True
```

Comment: I think you should POST the xml instead of PUTing it.

Comment: POST is used to create the file, PUT edits them. I found the solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the answer.

It just a bit off from what I was trying to do. The only real problem was the address I was using.

the address should have read:

```
Dim gUrl As String = ("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/" & workspace & "/datastores/" & ds & "/featuretypes/alignment.xml")
```

It was a bit confusing because I could not find an alignment.xml file directly, but when I put the address into the browser, I got data.

the rest of the code worked after that.